# web scraping dynamic list

Tags: list, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="col col-1-1"><h2 class="heading">Flowers</h2><ul class="icon-list">          <li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter">
            <svg class="icon icon--medium">
              <use xlink:href="https://"></use>
            </svg>
            measure 1<span class="icon-list__count">81</span>          </li>
                  <li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter">
            <svg class="icon icon--medium">
              <use xlink:href="https://"></use>
            </svg>
            measure 2 <span class="icon-list__count">52</span>          </li>
                  <li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter">
            <svg class="icon icon--medium">
              <use xlink:href="https://"></use>
            </svg>
            measure 3<span class="icon-list__count">29</span>          </li>
        </ul></div>
```

This is one example of a list of measures for one type of flowers. How to scrape the value of the measures and store in a python dictionary? Hope the code would be flexible to allow for the possibility that on another pager there might be measure 2 and 3 only, or measure 3 and 4 (a new measure not appearing on this page), or completely new measure 4 and 5.

New to python - would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is the best when you are scraping a more static and less dynamic website.
Try using unique identifiers present in a tag to navigate in this tree like structure. This piece of code will give you a dictionary with *measure n* as key and *value* as its value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '<div class="col col-1-1"><h2 class="heading">Flowers</h2><ul class="icon-list"><li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter"><svg class="icon icon--medium"><use xlink:href="https://"></use></svg>measure 1<span class="icon-list__count">81</span></li><li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter"><svg class="icon icon--medium"><use xlink:href="https://"></use></svg>measure 2 <span class="icon-list__count">52</span></li><li class="col col-1-2 no-gutter"><svg class="icon icon--medium"><use xlink:href="https://"></use></svg>measure 3<span class="icon-list__count">29</span></li></ul></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

li_tags = soup.find_all('li') # ['measure 181', 'measure 2 52', 'measure 329']
span_tags = soup.find_all('span',class_='icon-list__count') #  ['81', '52', '29']

li_list= []

for li in li_tags:
    li_list.append(li.text)

measure_dict = {}

for i in range(len(li_list)):
    li_list[i] = re.sub(span_tags[i].text,'',li_list[i])  #converting 'measure 181 into 'measure 1' and likewise
    measure_dict[li_list[i]] = span_tags[i].text     # if you want the values as integers then use int(span_tags[i].text) in this line

print(measure_dict)


 #{'measure 1': '81', 'measure 2 ': '52', 'measure 3': '29'}
```

The code will be flexible if the identifier I have used here `class = 'icon-list__count'` is present in every page you access and moreover when it also contains the data that you want to scrape. So you can hope it's the same and if not you have to traverse into the html tags to find your desired data by identify them on your own.

If in case the website uses Javascript() in the place where you want to scrape then it's better to use `Selenium` as it's a better scraping tool for dynamic websites.

**Advice:**
Reading the documentation of the module is far more helpful than watching random YT videos in the long run!
Try using `re` module whenever you want to play with strings, it's much better than the pre-defined methods in `string`